# How does one say "in a manner of speaking" in German?

Tags: phrase-request

Google translate gives "in eine Weise zu sprechen" but that strikes me as a literal translation that doesn't have the right "ring" to it. Is that, in fact, the best translation or is there a better one?

Comment: This is indeed a word-for-word "translation" and it not only doesn't have the right ring to it - it is utter nonsense and *totally* unidiomatic. :) Google translate is an invention of the devil.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

"Sozusagen", a compound of "so zu sagen".

Comment: ..which word-for-word translate to the equivalent 'so to say'.

Answer (score 4):

Two of the possible translation of "*manner*" are indeed "*Art*" or "*Weise*", in German often combined:

> In einer Art und Weise

Thus, "*in (such) a manner*" can be translated with "*in einer Weise*" or "*derart*". <sup>[dict.leo](http://dict.leo.org/ende?lp=ende&lang=de&searchLoc=0&cmpType=relaxed&sectHdr=on&spellToler=&search=manner)</sup>

However, in this example you shouldn't translate it like that. "*In a manner of speaking*" is a phrase with a particular meaning and thus you need to find the German equivalent of that saying. Some examples how to translate "*manner of speaking*" are also given by [dict.leo](http://dict.leo.org/ende?lp=ende&lang=de&searchLoc=0&cmpType=relaxed&sectHdr=on&spellToler=&search=in%20a%20manner%20of%20speaking). More examples on [bab.la](http://de.bab.la/woerterbuch/englisch-deutsch/in-a-manner-of-speaking).

Looking at the definition of "*in a manner of speaking*" ([link 1](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/in+a+manner+of+speaking), [link 2](http://oald8.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/dictionary/manner)) I think both suggestion "*sozusagen*" and "*gewissermaßen*" do hit the spot most often.